# Google Ad's error (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});

Tags: wordpress, adsense, google-ads-script

I've placed the ads on the WordPress site it's working fine at the time but after a while the google ads didn't display
Before:

```js
<!-- wp:html -->
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-9310298206025962"
     crossorigin="anonymous">
     
     </script>
<!-- Display Ad Unit 1 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9310298206025962"
     data-ad-slot="9808339852"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
<!-- /wp:html -->

<!-- /wp:html -->
<amp-ad width="100vw" height="320"
     type="adsense"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9310298206025962"
     data-ad-slot="9808339852"
     data-auto-format="rspv"
     data-full-width="">
  <div overflow=""></div>
</amp-ad>
<!-- /wp:html -->
```

After a while above code turns into this:

```html
   (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```

Comment: You can simply use Adinserter plugin to insert ads

Answer (score 1):

If you have placed the above code in the HTML through **WordPress default plugin/HTML** method then just remove it. Use some plugins called (Ad Inserter or Advance Ads) and then this error will be removed.

**Method/Solution 2:** If you are using some theme builders like Elementor etc just uses their own HTML code source to put your Adsense code.

Answer (score 0):

The block is causing the error. Change the input format from HTML (block). Try to use the native wordpress Block.